# Selecting options in a select via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have a select with the following options:

```
<select>
     <option value="1">A</option>
     <option value="2">B</option>
     <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

I don't know what the values are, but in my JQuery code, I want to select option two because I know that the text is B (but nothing else).

How can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
$('option:contains("B")').prop('selected', true);
```

Alternatively:

```
$('option')
    .filter(function() {
        return this.text == 'B'; 
    })
    .prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: $("option:contains("B")").attr('selected', 'selected');

Comment: is contains really the only way, there's no like test is kinda thing?

Comment: @chris given you another option in the answer

Answer (score 3):

If you're not sure what the values are, but know what the text inside is, you can use the `:contains()` selector to get the appropriate option, get its value, *then* set the select.

Note that `:contains()` performs a substring match, so `:contains(foo)` will select both `<p>foo</p>` and `<p>barfoobar</p>` (as [ThiefMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/thiefmaster) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715466/selecting-options-in-a-select-via-jquery/10715529#comment13915710_10715529)).

For more granular control on selection, you'll want the `.filter()` option I've mentioned farther down.

```
// relevant option
//     : not entirely sure if .val() will get an option's value
var _optionval = $('option:contains("B")').attr('value');

// set select value
$('select').val(_optionval);
```

#### EDIT

I'm sharing the following based off of your comment on Jack's answer.

`:contains()` is basically designed to perform a matching against an element's contents. No going around that.

You can, however, use something like `.filter()` to write more complicated code.

```
$('option').filter(function () {

    // we want the option (or optionS) with text that starts with "foo"
    return $(this).text().indexOf('foo') === 0;

    // or maybe just something with an exact match
    //
    // return $(this).text() === 'foo';
});
```

Comment: `:contains()` does a substring match so you want to use `.filter()` with `return $(thid).text() == 'B';`

Comment: Just re-read the documentation on `:contains()`, and it turns out you're completely correct. TIL.

Answer (score 2):

```
<select id="select_id">
 <option value="1">A</option>
 <option value="2">B</option>
 <option value="3">C</option>
</select>

$("#select_id option").each(function (){
   if($(this).text()=='B'){
       // DO what you want to  
   }
});
```

this code will select your any option in select field with text "B". i think this is what you want

Comment: yeah but it's a loop to go through N times

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Comment: This won't do it - you probably meant `jQuery("#select_id option").each(...`.

Comment: @chris yes you have to loop through all values when you have to select "B" if may be in some case it is not 2nd value and you have to select just "B"

Comment: @Chris - You can exit the `.each()` loop early by returning false from your callback function once a match is found.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (make sure you give your select an ID, i've used `mySelect`):

```
$("#mySelect").val($("#mySelect:option:contains('B')").val());
```

Comment: $("#mySelect:option:contains('B')").attr('value')

Comment: @ThulasiRam `.val()` is shorthand for `.attr("value")` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('option').each(function(){
    var t=this
    if(t.text=='B'){
       t.selected='selected';
    }
});​
```

Comment: Instead of `var t = $(this)[0]` you can just use `this` inside the function

Comment: No need for the `t` variable either, just use `this.text` and `this.selected`.